# Fulltext search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a simple search page on my site but finding it difficult to get full text search working as I would expect it to word.

Example search:

```
select *
from Movies
where contains(Name, '"Movie*" and "2*"')
```

Example data:

```
Id  Name
------------------
1   MyMovie 
2   MyMovie Part 2
3   MyMovie Part 3
4   MyMovie X2
5   Other Movie
```

Searches like `"movie*"` return no results since the term is in the middle of a work.

Searches like `"MyMovie*" and "2*"` only return MyMovie Part 2 and not MyMovie Part X2

It seems like I could just hack together a dynamic SQL query that will just
`and name like '%movie%' and name like '%x2%'` and it would work better than full text search which seems odd since it's a large part of SQL but doesn't seem to work as good as a simple like usage.

I've turned off my stop list so the number and single character results appear but it just doesn't seem to work well for what I'm doing which seems rather basic.

Comment: Why you just can't  use something: name like '%movie%2%' ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко that is going to have horrible performance on large tables with big fields, that is the entire point of full text indexing.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко Searching for things like "part 2 mymovie" wouldn't be found either since it has to be in the correct order

Comment: While this can be done in SQL Server, I'd really advice to use Elasticsearch to do such kind of queries, you'll thank me later.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I've used ES in other projects and it's pretty overkill for my use case

Comment: I think this might involve creating a custom [Word Braker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search) that splits PascalCase words but i have no idea how to create a new one to register it with the sql server.

Comment: Maybe it's an overkill, but I'll stick to what I've said. It's just going to be better to go that path.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Maybe better for solving this problem but not better to have increased monthly cost and another server to maintain.

Comment: Use Elastic Search, do not think your "overkill" thought regarding Elastic Search is actually accurate

Comment: @BrianOgden It is accurate. I'm not paying for another server/service and maintaining it. This should be a relatively simple task.

Comment: @user3953989 Elastic Search is free

Comment: @BrianOgden The software is free. The hosting and bandwidth are not.

Comment: _I could just hack together a dynamic SQL query that will just and name like '%movie%' and name like '%x2%' and it would work better_ as already stated, this would be very slow on large tables, whereas Search would be very fast. How you want your search to work is up to you. You can pad your end-users search terms with `*` if you like.  Going by this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, contains has a lot of functionality not available in `LIKE`, for example _near_ and _synonyms_

Answer (score 0):

select
*
from Movies
where 
name like ('%Movie%')
or name like ('%2%')
;

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Movies where freetext(Name, ' "Movie*" or "2*" ')
```